# How do I send Ajax post request using urllib2 or Mechanize after opening the page?

Tags: ajax, post, python-2.7, urllib2, mechanize

This is the page on which I am working: www.walmart.com/ip/Sony-Xperia-ZL-LTE-C6506-5-Smartphone-Unlocked/24566601

On this page there are 3 color options available for a device & whenever I click on one of the color box, price for that color variant of device gets loaded through Ajax Post request to server.

I am trying to send this request using Python, below are the codes I have used so far.

Code 1:

```
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1;Trident/5.0)'
values = {'ajaxCalls':'AjaxUrl|/catalog/fetch_dynamic_data.do?item_id=24566602|CallbackFunction|WALMART.bot.AjaxInterface.handleSuccess_DynamicData|RtnRespType|json|timeoutSetting|300|'}
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(colorlink, data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
page = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

colorlink is url I mentioned above

Code 2:

```
values = {'ajaxCalls':'AjaxUrl|/catalog/fetch_dynamic_data.do?item_id=24566602|CallbackFunction|WALMART.bot.AjaxInterface.handleSuccess_DynamicData|RtnRespType|json|timeoutSetting|300|'}               
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.7) Gecko/20100713 Firefox/3.6.7"
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
req = mechanize.Request(colorlink, values,headers)
cj.add_cookie_header(req)
res = mechanize.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res)
```

colorlink is the url mentioned above.

I copied mechanize code from one of the stackoverflow questions and tried to use it for my case but it didn't work. I came across **TypeError** probably because of **values** variable which mechanize is regarding as dict.

Also, I was not able to send **Timestamp** value in POST parameters as it requires current time, I don't know how do I do that.

Please help me in resolving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `timestamp` from `time.time()`. Plus, I'd go with `requests`:

```
import requests
import time

REFERER = "http://www.walmart.com/ip/Sony-Xperia-ZL-LTE-C6506-5-Smartphone-Unlocked/24566601"
ORIGIN = "http://www.walmart.com"

timestamp = str(time.time()).replace(".", "")
URL = "http://www.walmart.com/catalog/ajaxBridgeInterface.do?timestamp=%s" % timestamp

data = {'ajaxCalls': 'AjaxUrl|/catalog/fetch_dynamic_data.do?item_id=24566602|CallbackFunction|WALMART.bot.AjaxInterface.handleSuccess_DynamicData|RtnRespType|json|timeoutSetting|300|',
        'timestamp': timestamp}

response = requests.post(URL, data=data, headers={'Referer': REFERER, 'Origin': ORIGIN})

print response.json()
```

UPD: here' an example using selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.walmart.com/ip/Sony-Xperia-ZL-LTE-C6506-5-Smartphone-Unlocked/24566601')

elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('SwatchAnchor')

for element in elements:
    element.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    print driver.find_element_by_class_name('bigPriceText1').text + driver.find_element_by_class_name('smallPriceText1').text 

driver.close()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: response.json is printing this `[{u'url': u'/catalog/fetch_dynamic_data.do?item_id=24566602', u'callback': u'WALMART.bot.AjaxInterface.handleSuccess_DynamicData', u'respText': {u's2hDDM': [], u's2sDDM': [], u'shippingPrices': []}}]` Prices value are empty in this JSON, can you help me in identifying the source for price values then which are getting loaded on webpage.

Comment: I've seen that prices are empty. Though chrome browser developer tools show me empty prices too. Are you ok to switch to in-browser tool like `selenium`?

Comment: Yeah, I am but I don't know how to use it. Yes, I also looked through firebug, price values were empty.

Comment: Ok, I've added an example using selenium. Check please.

Comment: I am getting this error "WindowsError: [Error 87] The parameter is incorrect" Is it because I am using Firefox portable and I don't have it installed? Also, if elements contain all the color related boxes, after clicking it can I directly look for price value using .find method?

Comment: I used this `driver = webdriver.Ie()` and now I am getting this error `NoSuchWindowException: Message: u'Unable to get browser' ` also elements variable is empty.

Comment: Yeah, try installing firefox.

Comment: I can't, don't have admin rights. I made it work for IE only, but now I don't know how to fetch price values for each click made. My `element` variable contains these values now for 3 clicks: `[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x0000000003351400>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x0000000003351470>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x0000000003351358>]`